# Changed WC tables into utf8mb4 unicode and broke site

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, utf-8, woocommerce

Ok, here is a tip: If you don't know what you're doing don't do it! I have a live webshop that I just somehow broke and I think it's related to me changing, after reading here on this site how good the `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` is.

The problem that occurs is that when my customers with letters like ÅÄÖ or é á etc is shopping and paying, the payment goes through but WooCommerce is somehow not handling it and sending me a "cancelled order" though it's been paid for. Now the reason i think its my change that did this is because those who breaks are the ones with those weird letters. Example my customer `"Andersén"` is displayed on my billing invoice: `"AndersÃ©n"`

What can I do?

Comment: Where did you make the change? Have you tried reverting the changes?

Comment: In PhPMyadmin! I went into table, clicked "Operaitons" and changed coalition. Did this for all tables and now suddenly I'm getting them as cancelled when the characters is foreign. Do I need to do something to charset? Like set a charse to all tables?

Comment: what did you use _before_ the change?

Comment: Set old collation, probably it was utf8_unicode_ci, but you can check it....

Comment: @RomeoPatrick Accept the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43119207/3290256 because you clearly used the code in your website.

Answer (score 0):

**If you don't know what you're doing don't do it!** -- You hit the nail on the head!  And `CHARACTER SETs` in MySQL is such a rat's nest of things that can go wrong.

**Cause**

`Ã©` for `é` is *probably* Mojibake.

There are 4 (sometimes 5) stages at which you could have messed up.  There are 2 (probably more) ways that you could have compounded the problem when you tried to fix it.

1. What bytes did you have?  `é` in latin1 is one byte, hex `E9`.  In utf8 (and utf8mb4), it is 2 bytes, hex `C3A9`.  (For Mojibake, you *probably* had `C3A9`.)
2. Show us the `SET NAMES` (or `set_charset()` or ...) in your client.  Ultimately it should be 'utf8mb4'; what was it to start with?  Mojibake can occur for either 'latin1' or 'utf8'.  It should ultimately be utf8/utf8mb4.
3. What `CHARACTER SET` is defined the column/table?  It should ultimately be utf8/utf8mb4, but converting existing data can be tricky.
4. The `<meta ...charset=...>` was probably missing or iso...; it should ultimately be `UTF-8` (with `-`, no `mb4`).

If you are lucky, and #4 was the *only* non-utf8 item, then adding/changing the meta-tag should have sufficed.

**Diagnose**

Please do this so we can figure out how bad the situation is:

```
SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM tbl WHERE ...
```

for the "Andersén" (or something else).

`416E64657273E96E` -- pure latin1; I don't expect this to happen;
`416E64657273C3A96E` -- Correctly stored as utf8/utf8mb4 (but incorrectly retrieved and/or rendered);
`416E64657273C383C2A96E` -- "double encoded" -- a messy situation.

Since the last two cases cases *probably* can turn into `AndersÃ©n`, I need to know which it is before launching into how to fix it.

[*Here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll) is my unfinished compendium of how to deal with all charset problems.  It includes two ways to `ALTER` the table; they are for *different* causes.  Doing the wrong one will only compound the problem.

**Cure**  *TBD*